# Why deleting/removing cookies in WordPress does not log me out from admin?

Tags: login, cookies, logout

I am really curious and I haven't found satisfactory answer in similar questions.

When deleting all of my cookies, I am still perfectly able to access my admin dashboard - why am I not returned back to login page and required to authenticate again? Why is it different in WordPress than in most other CMSs that deleting cookies still keeps my admin session valid somehow? Can someone explain to me in more details how and why this works this way?

To add additional explanation, when I clear cookies, top user/admin bar is no longer there (this is expected). However, if I directly access some wp-admin page (via bookmark, for example), then the bar is back and I can do anything I normally do as logged-in admin user.

Thank you

Comment: most likely you have some bad theme or plugin, or you use a mixed http and https setup

Comment: Hi Mark, I don't use mixed http/https (https is exclusive, all http auto redirected / in other words I use forced https). About the theme, hmm, will check this out, but how a frontend theme can affect admin side? About plugins, will check that, too. Thanks for the hints!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for those who are curious, and to the best of my knowledge/investigation: it turns out this was a strange bug/issue of Chrome Portable* version 47* I was using on my older laptop. It does not happen in other browsers and regular Chrome installation.

- (with Windows XP, because of EOL support)